# VB6 "IsNumeric()" behaviour in Windows 8/Windows 2012

Tags: windows-8, vb6, isnumeric

Using a VB6 app on Windows 7 both lines return TRUE, because somehow the decimal separator is not considered:

```
IsNumeric("123.45")
IsNumeric("123,45")
```

On Windows 8 or Windows 2012, the same code returns TRUE or FALSE depending on the regional settings. Considering the comma as decimal separator defined in regional settings, then:

```
IsNumeric("123.45") returns FALSE
IsNumeric("123,45") returns TRUE
```

Is there any way to restore the "old" behaviour without recompiling the app?

Comment: In regional settings you can set decimal symbol in `Numbers` tab to "." and decimal symbol in `Currency` tab to "," for both strings to be considered numeric. Btw, this has nothing to do with OS version as your original research implied.

Comment: @wqw: my tests confirm that OS is somehow related. In both OSs (Windows 7 and Windows 2012 Server) the decimal separator is "," for Number and Currency.

Comment: I'm using Bulgarian locale, both decimal symbols are "," and on Win7 x64 `IsNumeric("123.45") = False` -- just tested.

Comment: Have you checked the digit grouping symbol in regional settings? It's used to group digits, e.g. `1,000` is one thousand written with digit grouping symbol `","`. If your digit grouping symbol is `","` and your decimal separator is `"."` then `"123.45"` is a valid number `123.45`. Also `"123,45"` is a valid number `12345`.

Answer (score 3):

This is *not* a new issue with which version of Windows you are using.  It's always been based on the locale settings of the machine.

What I did for my application is I made my own functions:

```
Public Function IsNumber(ByRef Expression As Variant) As Boolean
    Select Case VarType(Expression)
    Case vbInteger, vbLong, vbSingle, vbDouble, vbCurrency, vbDate, vbBoolean, vbDecimal, vbByte
        IsNumber = True
    Case vbString
        Dim Negative As Boolean
        Dim Number As Boolean
        Dim Period As Boolean
        Dim Positive As Boolean
        Dim X As Long
        For X = 1& To Len(Expression)
            Select Case Mid$(Expression, X, 1&)
            Case "0" To "9"
                Number = True
            Case "-"
                If Period Or Number Or Negative Or Positive Then Exit Function
                Negative = True
            Case "."
                If Period Or Exponent Then Exit Function
                Period = True
            Case "E", "e"
                If Not Number Then Exit Function
                If Exponent Then Exit Function
                Exponent = True
                Number = False
                Negative = False
                Period = False
            Case "+"
                If Not Exponent Then Exit Function
                If Number Or Negative Or Positive Then Exit Function
                Positive = True
            Case vbSpace, vbTab, vbVerticalTab, vbCr, vbLf, vbFormFeed
                If Period Or Number Or Exponent Or Negative Then Exit Function
            Case Else
                Exit Function
            End Select
        Next X
        IsNumber = Number
    End Select
End Function
```

If you're dealing with strings explicitly, then you could simplify that function.  And also you likely don't want to deal with exponents, so this might be more suited:

```
Public Function IsNumber(ByRef Expression As String) As Boolean
    Dim Negative As Boolean
    Dim Number As Boolean
    Dim Period As Boolean
    Dim X As Long
    For X = 1& To Len(Expression)
        Select Case Mid$(Expression, X, 1&)
        Case "0" To "9"
            Number = True
        Case "-"
            If Period Or Number Or Negative Then Exit Function
            Negative = True
        Case "."
            If Period Then Exit Function
            Period = True
        Case vbSpace, vbTab, vbVerticalTab, vbCr, vbLf, vbFormFeed
            If Period Or Number Or Negative Then Exit Function
        Case Else
            Exit Function
        End Select
    Next X
    IsNumber = Number
End Function
```

When you are in need of converting the number, use `Str()` instead of `CLng()`/`CInt()`/`CDbl()`/`CSng()`/`Val()`.  `Str()` treats periods as decimals regardless of locale, just like my `IsNumber()` function above.

Comment: thank you, but I'm looking for a solution that don't requires recompilation of the program.